# MySql Set Up Computed Column does not work

Tags: mysql, sql, calculated-columns

My Goal is to have 3 Columns: "Date" ProductName" "ProductID" - ProductID consists of Date+ProductID (like: YY-MM-DD_Socks);

I tried using "Computed Columns" but I am getting the error that "AS" is an unrecognized data type (I have my Database in PhpMyAdmin)

Here is my Code:

```
CREATE TABLE origin (   
  Date DATE,    
  ProductName TEXT,     
  ProductID as (Concat(Date,'_',ProductName))
);
```

I am just learning MySQL so I guess that this is a easy problem that I face ;)

Thanks in advance for looking into this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL requires a type:

```
CREATE TABLE origin (   
  Date DATE,    
  ProductName TEXT, 
  Ticker TEXT,    
  ProductID TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS as (Concat(Date, '_', Ticker))
);
```

And `Ticker` needs to be a column.